# how to check event source is created or not in event viewer using cmd

Tags: cmd, event-viewer

I was created an event source in event viewer using cmd but now I want check before creating event source into event viewer that event source already created or not using cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [WEVTUtil](http://ss64.com/nt/wevtutil.html)

> Retrieve information about event logs and publishers. Archive logs in
>   a self-contained format, Enumerate the available logs, Install and
>   uninstall event manifests, run queries, Exports events (from an event
>   log, from a log file, or using a structured query) to a specified
>   file, Clear event logs.

Try the following:

```
WEVTUtil enum-publishers | findstr yoursourcename
```

where `yoursourcename` is the name of the event source your are looking for.

Comment: Thank's DavidPostill it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm not sure if this is feasable with cmd but you can test it with powershell (integrated in Windows since Windows 7?)

```
write-eventlog -logname Application -source TestApp -eventID 3001 -entrytype Information -message "MyApp added a user-requested feature to the display." -category 1 -rawdata 10,20
```

if it's not registered you'll an error something like this "write-eventlog : The source name "TestApp" does not exist on computer "localhost"."

hope this will help you.

regards

Answer (score 0):

```
EVENTCREATE [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] /ID eventid
        [/L logname] [/SO srcname] /T type /D description
```

Description:
    This command line tool enables an administrator to create
    a custom event ID and message in a specified event log.

---

For boot time checking using source name for any Windows version (as it varies).

```
wmic /append:"%userprofile%\desktop\DiskEvents.html" PATH Win32_NTLogEvent where  (sourcename='Autocheck' or sourcename='Winlogon' or sourcename='WinInit') get /format:HForm
```